# adding watermark text on image in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

```
            TextBlock text = new TextBlock();
            text.Text = "WATER MARK";
            text.Width = 150;
            text.Height = 50;
            text.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
            Grid grid = new Grid();
            grid.Height = 50;
            grid.Width = 150;
            RowDefinition rowDefinition = new RowDefinition();
            rowDefinition.Height = new GridLength(50, GridUnitType.Auto);

            grid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDefinition);
            Grid.SetRow(text, 0);
            grid.Children.Add(text);



            RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
            await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(grid);
            var pixelBuffer = await renderTargetBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();
```

Here I am trying to save the grid in which a textblock is added.But I am getting an exception that **value does not fall in the range** at RenderAsync().

I am getting the same exception even when i save that grid in which both image and textblock is added .

I am not getting any exception when i tried to save the grid which is defined in XAML.
But How to save that grid which is defined programatically .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UIElement` you want to render to a `RenderTargetBitmap` **needs** to be in the Visual Tree (rendered).

Here are a few remarks directly from the official [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap):

> Content that's in the tree but with its Visibility set to Collapsed won't be captured.
>
> Content that's not directly connected to the XAML visual tree and the content of the main window won't be captured. This includes Popup content, which is considered to be like a sub-window.
>
> For Windows Phone Store apps: the contents of a WebView control can't be rendered into a RenderTargetBitmap.
>
> Content that can't be captured will appear as blank in the captured image, but other content in the same visual tree can still be captured and will render (the presence of content that can't be captured won't invalidate the entire capture of that XAML composition).
>
> Content that's in the XAML visual tree but offscreen can be captured, so long as it's not Visibility=Collapsed or in the other restricted cases.

For your problem I would recommend you to create the watermark and its container in XAML but set opacity to 0.

Comment: Thank you Kristian Vukusic.